# Batch for reading a file and output line number + token?

Tags: batch-file, delayedvariableexpansion

This is what I want to do, a batch that reads a file (e.g. file.txt) and output line# + token.

This is what I tried to do (which obviously didn't work):

```
set count=0
set InputFile=file.txt
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A IN (%InputFile%) DO (
    set /a count+=1
    echo %count%. %%A
)
```

file.txt contains:

```
something,else,
something1,else1, 
something2,else2, 
something3,else3,
etc.
```

What I would like to output, is:

```
1. something
2. something1
3. something2
etc.
```

What this code is actually throwing in the output:

```
0. someting
0. something1
0. something2
etc
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file variable scope issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387098/batch-file-variable-scope-issue)

Comment: I have flagged your question as being a duplicate (see automatic comment above). The answer I provided applies to your case, and the explanation in MC ND's answer will tell you exactly what is happening with your batch file.

Comment: I don't get it, I tried adding setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion but it didn't change anything.
Are you sure that the answer provided applies?

Comment: Did you also change how you refer to your variable from `%count%` to `!count!`?

Comment: Just saw the problem. Using setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion plus !count! instead of %count% solved. THANKS!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` before you `FOR` loop.

Then change `echo %count%. %%A` to `echo !count!. %%A`.

Comment: No. The `set /a` command correctly takes the value even if it is not enclosed in exclamation marks. However, they _are_ required in the `echo !count!. %%A`